# Is there a way to display the users parameters in a RDLC Report

Tags: dataset, reportviewer

I have a requirement from a customer who requires that the parameters a user inputs into a report using RDLC to be displayed in the report. I am not talking about passing parameters to generate a report, I am talking about having some textboxes that shows the parameters that were to generate the report.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I have tried this, but http://www.ramto.com/blog/post/Using-RDLC-files-and-Microsoft-Report-Viewer-in-ASPNET.aspx, but it throws an error in the RDLC and says "the data set name is missing in the region 'DataSetName'".

Answer (score 0):

RightClick Textbox -> Under General Tab Click the Expression button for value -> Click Category Parameters -> Then Chose the Parameter.

The Textbox should show the Parameter value supplied to the ReportViewer control when the report is displayed.